# Advantage of using async socket server

Tags: c#, sockets

In which situration should we use an async socket (either Tcp or Udp) server over sync socket server?

If it's in client side, I understand that we used to use async so that it doesn't block the UI thread.. but I'm not sure why we need to use async on server side..

Comment: Use `sync socket server` without any threads and process incoming requests one-by-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, it's important to allow parallel processing of clients. If you're processing a large request for one client, you don't want a second client's connect request to time out. This does not mean that you *have* to use asynchronous methods though. You could easily create a separate thread for each connected client, and accept new clients in the main thread, all synchronously (and for Udp you could use queue the processing of each message in a thread from the ThreadPool).

The asynchronous socket methods already take care of the parallel-ness though (also by using separate threads), so it's a good technique to keep your server running smoothly.

Comment: +1. Synchronous code is often simple to write, so if you need to serve several only clients - synchronous code will be fine. Depending on load somewhere around 10-100 clients you'll have to swithc to async model.